# sudo systemctl restart apache2 fail

Tags: apache2, restart, wordpress

I tried web aparch2 on ubuntu16.04.
At first, it worked well. I install aparch2,mysql,php and tried info.php,it worked well.
Then I install wordpress and change the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf as:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I also change the mysql(create wordpress database) and  wp-config.php
(sudo mv wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php)
I follow:  https://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-lamp/
But I can't restart apache2.The message is follow:

```
liwenz@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
liwenz@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-04 10:28:31 EDT; 28s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22757 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 18640 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SU
  Process: 24828 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAIL

Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]:  *
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]: Output of config test was:
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]: apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]: The Apache error log may have more inform
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-cod

liwenz@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ journalctl -xe
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu apache2[24828]: The Apache error log may have more inform
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-cod
Aug 04 10:28:31 ubuntu sudo[24825]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for u
Aug 04 10:28:45 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:28:53 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:29:06 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:29:18 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:29:35 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:29:42 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:29:56 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:30:05 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:30:19 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
Aug 04 10:30:27 ubuntu dhclient[1078]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.13 on ens33 to 2
lines 1088-1110/1110 (END)
```

Comment: Looks like you cut off some of the lines. You should look in line 141 of whatever flie it's pointing to in this line: `Syntax error on line 141 of /etc`  But you cut off the rest of the line so we can't know where the error is.

Comment: Please maximize your terminal window in order to copy the entire lines of the output of `systemctl restart apache2.service`, then [edit] and update the question.

Comment: the line 139-141 in/etc/apache2/apache2.conf is:
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Answer (score 1):

the line 139-141 in/etc/apache2/apache2.conf is:

```
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
```

I think the error should be in mods-enabled/*.conf
I ever changed the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf,so I find the error in the file.
Now I could restart.
Thanks for your help!